# mailto link not working in Visualforce page

Tags: html

In my Visualforce page i have give the following line to open email to support group.

```
<apex:outputLink value="mailto:supportgroup@abccorp.com">
```

When i click the link nothing is happening. Need help in fixing this.

Thanks,

IRaj

Comment: Normally, this would look like `<apex:outputLink value="mailto:blah.com">Contact Support</apex:outputLink>`

Comment: above code is working fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: In which browser its not working ? And version ?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: Ok I got the solution for my problem. I did't had my default email program set.  I followed this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-default-e-mail-program) now its working for me. crop1645, AtulRajguru9, Jitendra Zaa thanks for your support and time.