# "mailto" link not working when visualforce page is rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, renderas

Firstly, I went through simimlar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61152/mailto-link-not-working-in-visualforce-page) posted here on SE but i believe it speaks as mailto link not working in visualforce page. For me, it is workng perfectly fine as expected n visualforce pages but doesnt work when the same page is rendered as pdf.

I tried outputlink, html anchor tag both of wihch are not working on final pdf rendered from below page.

Below is my code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                Click here
            </a>
            <br /><br />
            <a href="mailto:supportgroup@abccorp.com">
                Click Here !!!!
            </a>
            <br />

            <apex:outputLink value="http://www.google.com">Click here</apex:outputLink>
            <br /> <br />
            <apex:outputLink value="mailto:supportgroup@abccorp.com">Click here</apex:outputLink>            
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```